# HttpClient.GetAsync() returning 404 error in WinRT Xaml Application

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, httpclient

```
    private async Task<String> GetStringFromURI(String URIString)
    {
        Uri resourceUri;
        if (!Uri.TryCreate(URIString.Trim(), UriKind.Absolute, out resourceUri))
        {
            return null;
        }
        string responseText;
        try
        {
            response = await httpClient.GetAsync(resourceUri);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            responseText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            responseText = ex.ToString();
        }
        return responseText;
    }
```

This is my code when I send http url it works but https is not working. What could be the problem with that?

**Call from browser:**

[image]

**Call from Mobile:**

[image]

Comment: If you get a 404, you're requesting a resource that does not exist.

Comment: url simply returns json and when I paste same url on browser it works

Comment: If you browse to the address using the https url, do you get a certificate error? If so, then this is an issue with the certificate on the server. Has it expired for instance?

Comment: Yeah so maybe the site requires you to be logged on or something. Compare a working request to a request made from code using Fiddler.

Comment: I am editing my answer with the snapshot of fidler for both requests

Comment: editted my question]

Comment: Is my code is ok? This code works with https requests also? I am using same function in many places of my application but exception is thrown only in https request

Comment: You have to enable the option to decrypt HTTPS traffic (be sure to uncheck the option and revoke the Fiddler root certificate when done).

Comment: should I trust the Fiddler Root Certificate? It is asking me this

Comment: in result column of both request(browser and mobile) result code is 200. I think fiddler is creating problem there.

Comment: The Windows Phone runtime returns a 404 error if the certificate isn't trusted. Which means that 1/ It cannot work with Fiddler unless you add the Fiddler root certificate to your phone, and 2/ the original website has either an expired certificate, a self-signed certificate, or a certificate assigned to a different domain. Nothing you can do about it unless you're the owner of the said website

Comment: only windows Phone returns error in this case? Cause browser is returning the response

Comment: Same url is working for android phone :(

Comment: Yup, it's specific to Windows Phone apps